# APIs for exploring Haskell source

Tags: haskell

I need an API (or set of APIs) that can:

1. provide a listing of all packages in hackage
2. given a package name, provide a listing of all modules in that package
3. given a module name, provide a list of all functions and types exported from that module
4. given a module name + function name, provide the type signature, documentation, and definition of said function
5. given a module name + type name, provide the definition and documentation of that type

Are any of these available on public APIs? HTTP interfaces with JSON output would be the most convenient, but any type of API will probably do.

My goal is to create a multi-paned package explorer, similar to the class browser you find in Smalltalk IDEs. The only thing close to this I've seen is the Browser in Leksah, which I gave up on for a number of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Well, aside from looking at the Leksah source itself (which is a good idea!), I'd recomend looking at the source for hoogle: https://github.com/ndmitchell/hoogle

But also, pursuit in the purescript world is quite cool to look at, as that's got a kind of hybrid of hoogle (context-insensitive function / module / anything lookup) mixed with hackage (package browsing, etc).

I think you're probably going to have to build the API yourself because there's no readymade packages for doing such things out of the box. Good luck!